How to duplicate Android notification layout

The first notification is the original notification and the second notification is the notification I duplicated.
However, even though it is the same device, you can see that the positions of the two notification icons are different.
I want to duplicate the position of the icon in the original notification to match its location.
The code below is where I copy the original notification.
private fun sendDelayedNotification(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
    val senderName = sbn.notification.extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE) ?: "Unknown"  // 발신자의 TITLE 추출
    val uniqueNotificationId = senderName .hashCode()  // TITLE만을 기반으로 고유 ID 생성
    val channelID = "delayed_channel_id"
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelID, "Delayed Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    val originalNotification = sbn.notification
    val extras = originalNotification.extras
    val smallIcon = originalNotification.smallIcon
    val largeIcon = originalNotification.getLargeIcon()
    val smallIconCompat = IconCompat.createFromIcon(this, smallIcon)
    val largeIconBitmap = largeIcon?.let { iconToBitmap(it, this) }
    val title = originalNotification.extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE) ?: "Notification"
    val text = originalNotification.extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT) ?: "No details available"
    // 알림을 클릭할 때 액션 정의
    val contentIntent = originalNotification.contentIntent
    // 새로운 알림 생성 및 발송
    val newNotification = smallIconCompat?.let {
        NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelID)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(it) // 아이콘 설정
            .setLargeIcon(largeIconBitmap)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addExtras(Bundle().apply { putBoolean("isDelayedNotification", true) })
            .setExtras(Bundle(extras))  // 모든 추가 데이터를 복사
            .build()
    }
    notificationManager.notify(uniqueNotificationId, newNotification)

}`

